# Why do i get a "C4103: alignment changed after including header" with VS2019 and /std:c++latest

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

Compiling the small testprogram

```
#include <string>
#pragma pack(show)
template<typename TTTTT, int OOOOO>
void xxxxxx(TTTTT(&)[OOOOO]){}
#pragma pack(show)
#include <locale>
int main() {}
```

with the newest VS2019 V16.9.0 for x64 I'm getting a bunch of C4103 warnings about alignment changes:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\system_error(18,1): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xiosbase(12,1): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\streambuf(11,1): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\xlocbuf(11,1): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\locale(11,1): warning C4103: alignment changed after including header, may be due to missing #pragma pack(pop)
```

[Here's a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dz4f4q).

I can't find out the cause.
The alignment seems to be changed by the template definition but i don't understand why and also not why the #pragma pack(show) after it outputs two warning lines.

Comment: Maybe include  a few #pragma pack(show) before and after the includes to see if/how packing is changing?

Comment: @DS_London Thanks! I didn't think of that. I've edited the question.

Comment: Perhaps put the 'show's directly above and below each include statement? So first line of code is a 'show', then #include <string> then another 'show'. Then one more on the line after #include <locale>.

Comment: When I put the same code in VS, I don't get the C4103 warnings, but I do get the C4810 warnings from the pack(show). I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.5. I'll see if I can get v16.9 and re-try.

Comment: @DS_London Thanks! Did you also set /std:c++latest ? Initially i have put em on every line but the output only changed from before and after the template so i removed all others. Here's a godbolt showing all of them: https://godbolt.org/z/9jjofq

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community v16.9 now. The include directory is 14.28.29910. I was compiling as Debug/x86 without any warnings. If I switch to Debug/x64, I get the same warnings as you. Interestingly, if I only have one 'show' right about the #include <locale>, I get two lines of output for the pack info, just as you do. If I take out the #include <locale> I get dont get the C4103 warnings.

Comment: Looking inside <string> and <locale> it looks as if they both change the packing to 8 bytes, but both also have the pack(pop) at the end which is supposed to change it back to whatever it was before (ie 16). But it is only <locale> which is prompting the C4103 warnings. <locale> doesnt seem however to be changing it back for some reason.

Comment: @DS_London https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-160 mentions that 8 is the default value (which turns out to be wrong for x64 builds: https://godbolt.org/z/9Wb8aj). Here's a SO entry about why 16 on x64: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017996/why-do-x64-projects-use-a-default-packing-alignment-of-16

Comment: While investigating it, i output the full PP output to a file and manually compared all push/pop pairs and they all matched perfectly. Feels like there is some hidden magic going on somewhere.

Comment: To add another wrinkle ... if you move #include <locale> to above the template<...> declaration, the 4013 warnings go away and the number of warnings matches the number of pack(show)s ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229562/discussion-between-ds-london-and-jesses).

Comment: [Known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-c4103-in-visual-studio-166-update/1057589) since 16.6, Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > "Conformance mode" = No seems to be a workaround.